# Get dll metadata in Linux environment

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core, .net-assembly

I want to be able to get the metadata of any `dll` (supporting dotnet versions back as far as possible), in a Linux environment (that is, when running any `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk` docker images).

Could that be achieved?

By metadata, I mean everything I can tell about the code without loading it (most important - namespaces, version).

I've observed [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Assembly_ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom_System_String_), but it doesn't seem to support pre-dotnet-core versions.

I'm not limited to a programming languages, only to Linux-based runtime.

Comment: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/blob/master/doc/Command%20Line.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AssemblyMetadata` from `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` package you can read the content of a dll like Version,  Module, Type, Reference, Property, and pretty much everything

```
var path = @"path/to/dll/file.dll";
var metadata = AssemblyMetadata.CreateFromFile(path);
var module = metadata.GetModules().First();
Console.WriteLine(module.Name);

var reader = module.GetMetadataReader();

var assemblyDef = reader.GetAssemblyDefinition();
Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(assemblyDef.Name));
Console.WriteLine(assemblyDef.Version.ToString());

foreach (var typeDefHandle in reader.TypeDefinitions)
{
    var typeDef = reader.GetTypeDefinition(typeDefHandle);
    var fullName = (reader.GetString(typeDef.Namespace) + "::" + reader.GetString(typeDef.Name));
    Console.WriteLine(fullName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not make any of the standard tools work outside Windows (ilspy, dnspy, ildasm)

However `exiftool`, referenced in  [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86147/viewing-dll-and-exe-file-properties-attributes-via-the-command-line/518908), seems to work fine for providing some metadata, though its still limited.

Example output for `exiftool Newtonsoft.Json.net45.dll`:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.73
File Name                       : Newtonsoft.Json.net45.dll
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 660 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:04:22 02:06:26+03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2019:10:28 10:11:25+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2019:10:28 10:09:56+02:00
File Permissions                : rwxr-xr-x
File Type                       : Win32 DLL
File Type Extension             : dll
MIME Type                       : application/octet-stream
Machine Type                    : Intel 386 or later, and compatibles
Time Stamp                      : 2092:04:05 06:43:32+03:00
Image File Characteristics      : Executable, Large address aware, DLL
PE Type                         : PE32
Linker Version                  : 48.0
Code Size                       : 665088
Initialized Data Size           : 2048
Uninitialized Data Size         : 0
Entry Point                     : 0xa42ba
OS Version                      : 4.0
Image Version                   : 0.0
Subsystem Version               : 6.0
Subsystem                       : Windows command line
File Version Number             : 12.0.2.23222
Product Version Number          : 12.0.2.0
File Flags Mask                 : 0x003f
File Flags                      : (none)
File OS                         : Win32
Object File Type                : Dynamic link library
File Subtype                    : 0
Language Code                   : Neutral
Character Set                   : Unicode
Comments                        : Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET
Company Name                    : Newtonsoft
File Description                : Json.NET
File Version                    : 12.0.2.23222
Internal Name                   : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Legal Copyright                 : Copyright © James Newton-King 2008
Legal Trademarks                :
Original File Name              : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Product Name                    : Json.NET
Product Version                 : 12.0.2+4ab34b0461fb595805d092a46a58f35f66c84d6a
Assembly Version                : 12.0.0.0
```